# I need to use the WHERE clause with a value of an element

Tags: mysql, database, forms

I'm developing a database to be used in a school here to store data on payments and students. Everything is going smoothly and I'm almost done but recently I have the need to filter some elements in one of my forms, I understand I have to use the clause `WHERE` in sql, but I don't really know much about it.

I have an element that's basically a search bar, you have to put the ID of a student there and it should display the payments that student made over one specific year. I have trouble filtering that ID and I have found very little documentation of this `WHERE` clause, I just want something like `WHERE student.id = getElementbyId(id.searchbar'').value;`  ,look for an specific value that is written in an element but not necessarily stored in a database.

I would really appreciate your help, I'm sure this is a really dumb question.

Comment: Please show some code, something.  this questions too broad.

Comment: I have a form that you can manage directly from a website, just your regular xml form, one of the elements of the form is for manually inputting the ID of a student, below that element there's a box where the results are supposed to be displayed. And they are, it displays everything, so I want to filter it so it only shows values stored in a database named "payments" that have the same ID (in a column named ID) that was filled in the first element.